# What does this limit represent for this function?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, suppose we have the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f(x,y) - f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}$$

The absolute value bars on the top is optional, but I just wanted to make everything positive.

What happens if the limit is equal to $1$? It looks as if the limit is a representation of some sort of derivative. Since both $x$ and $y$ seem to be both varying, I cannot tell which, perhaps it is some sort of gradient function? I am sure.

Note that

$f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$; $f(a,b) = (f_1(a,b),f_2(a,b))$. So the absolute value bars transform my limit to

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f_1(x,y) - f_1(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}} + \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f_2(x,y) - f_2(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}$$

Comment: If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, note that the absolute value bars convert this to a magnitude, a function into $\mathbb R$.  Is that what you mean?  When you have a $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}$ that exists at all, it exists no matter how you let $(x,y)$ approach $(a,b)$.  This is very powerful.

Comment: $f$ has two components. So the absolute value bars is over the sum of the differences of the components of $f(x,y)$ and $f(a,b)$

Comment: More normally it would be the magnitude of the vector, the square root of the sum of the squares of the components.  So $|(\pm 3, \pm 4)|=5$

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question

Comment: consider a simpler case of just $f_1=x+y$ at origin. You notice that the limit does not exist. That is the typical situation. So are you asking for the exceptional cases where the limit exists?

Comment: Yes; 15character

Comment: Let's put $(a,b)=(0,0)$ then  denominator is just $r$, distance from origin. It looks like $f_i$ must be a primarily radial function at origin, with no "strong" dependence on $\theta$ there.

Comment: Like $f(r,\theta)=r g(r,\theta)$ and $\lim_{r\to 0}g(r,\theta)$ should exist.

Comment: But recall (a,b) is arbitrary

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition of the || function, the limit cannot exist.  First take the limit for fixed $y$, and we get $f(x,b)\approx f(a,b)\pm (x-a,0)$ and then for fixed $x$ we get $f(a,y) \approx f(a,b) \pm (0,y-b)$.  If $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ we then have $f(x,y) \approx f(a,b)\pm (x-a,0)\pm (0,y-b)$  Then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f(x,y) - f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}$ along a diagonal line of slope $\pm 1$ is $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ One could claim this is a reason for using the usual $||$

Comment: How are you getting $\pm (x - a,0)$?

Comment: @sizz:  from the definition of derivative.  Since the second argument doesn't change, all the variation must come from the first.  Now we have a single variable function with derivative $\pm 1$.

Comment: That's what I mean. How did you know the single variable derive is 1?

Comment: @sizz:  feed it to the definition of derivative.  Use the fact that the limit is given to be $1$

Comment: You aren't given the (single variable derivative) limit is $1$.

Comment: @sizz:  yes, I am.  That is the point of my comment to OP that the limit has to be correct no matter how you approach the point.  A classic example is $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac {xy}{x^2+y^2}$ which is $0$ along the axes, but $\frac 12$ along $x=y$, so the 2D limit doesn't exist.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion, that or I am really behind. Suppose we hold $y = b$, then would get the following limit $$\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f_1(x,b) - f_1(a,b)}{x - a}$$ How did you deduce this limit is $1$?

Comment: @sizz:  We are given then that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f(x,y) - f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=1$  If we approach along the $x$ direction, $y=b$

Comment: yes we were given that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f(x,y) - f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=1$, but this is a limit where we approach (a,b) at the same time. Are we actually allow to set $y = b$ and do $$\lim_{(x,b)\to(a,b)} \dfrac{|f(x,b) - f(a,b)|}{|x - a|}=1$$?

Comment: @sizz:  yes, you can approach $(0,0)$ on any path you like.  If you don't get the same limit on all of them, the limit doesn't exist.  Two comments ago, I mentioned approaching along $x=y$.  There is also the classic $\frac {xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ where the limit fails to exist because you can approach along $x=y^2$